What is the purpose of the relay and transistor in this circuit?
I want to build this fingerprint sensor lock system but I don't understand what is going on in the circuit. I understand the relay helps switch the solenoid but what does the transistor do?
The website I'm using doesn't really explain a lot but they gave a schematic that I think is wired wrong in certain areas. Like the relay for some reason is wired to 9V and 5V for some reason plus there's no ground (unless that's right.)
This is the website I'm looking at:
https://how2electronics.com/esp32-fingerprint-sensor-security-system/#google_vignette


The schematic is drawn upside down and looks like Q1 is upside down on top of it.

There is a "short" between GND and 3.3 V on the pin 1 of ESP32.

At the very least I think the relay is drawn backwards. It should be mirrored horizontally.

The purpose of the transistor is to provide higher current for the D23 signal from the ESP32 to drive the relay coil. The diode D1 reduces the inductive kickback from the relay coil so it won't damage the transistor. It makes sense that the "solenoid lock" plug runs through the relay contacts, as this isolates whatever is plugged into it from the rest of the circuit. (My sketch shows it running through the N.C. contacts but it might need to be changed to N.O. depending on the application.)
EDIT: I revised my pic to reverse Q1 and D1. Agreed, this is a poor schematic and there could be other problems.

Q1 and D1 look to be upside down as well.  This is a poorly drawn schematic.  Beware.

Hi thank you for your help and explanation! But why does the COM pin get 5V and the bottom of the coil gets 9V? shouldn't there be ground on the bottom coil?

In my sketch, 5V goes to one side of the relay coil and the other side is grounded through the transistor which acts as a switch. Coils are not polarity sensitive, but if there's a suppression diode like D1 it must be oriented the right way. The relay contacts will send 9V to pin 1 of the solenoid, with pin 2 tied to ground.

Goodness, that schematic is a shambolic hot mess. Vcc and GND are reversed on the OLED vs. ESP32.
I suppose the 7805 is supposed to reduce 9V to 5V and the ESP32 module provides the 3.3V as an output.
As drawn the diode is the wrong way 'round and the transistor is connected wrong. And the relay is wrong. It should look like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Deliberately passing GND current through the ESP32 module is also a good way to make your life more interesting.

Hi, thank you for the explanation! So does that mean the solenoid goes to NC and 9V goes to the ON? I'm confused on how the relay is supposed to look like now and I don't understand why the relay is getting 9V and 5V since it takes 9V to charge the solenoid

Most likely the solenoid goes to N.O. and 9V to COM or vice-versa (assuming one side of the solenoid is indeed grounded) since you'd want the solenoid to be de-energized if the relay is de-energized, but I trust very little on that schematic. N.C. would be unused. The job of the relay is to switch the 9V at high current using the 5V supply for relay coil power and controlled via the transistor by the weak 3.3V input from the ESP32.
